# Advanced border styles - CSS or images?

Tags: css, border

[image]

I'm trying to make the borders of a div look like this, with transparency, drop shadow, and inner dashed border. Is there a way to do this with CSS/jQuery, or am I better off just using images?

Comment: How does the site from the screenshot do it?

Comment: It's a photoshop file that I created. I'm trying to create the site in code now.

Comment: What browsers are you looking to support? Do you want to support back through IE6, or only modern browsers (IE9, Chrome, FF, Safari)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **HTML**

```
<div id="rounded">    
    ​<div id="yellow">
        <div id="dashed"></div>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

and **CSS**

```
#rounded {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#yellow {
    background-color: #F7EFE2;
    height: 96%;
    padding: 10px;
}
#dashed {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dashed #E8C55F;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LXS3V/)
​

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but pointed me in the right direction. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
border-style:dashed;
```

If you need more check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-style)

Answer (score -1):

While you could possibly do it with CSS3/HTML 5, if the size of the box is fixed, I would use images. CSS3 is only supported in modern browsers, whereas images are supported in older ones as well.

If this is a popup then that would change matters a little bit and you would want to do the drop shadow some other way than an image.

Comment: This answer is more of a comment. Please provide a detailed answer.